# How to get the value out of Knockout function

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout and I'm trying to build function that will return a value, The problem is that I'm computing the value inside internal function, and I don't find a way to get the value out of this function.

Thats what I have so far

JS

```
var vm = {
    myResponse: ko.observable(),
    computedValue: ko.observable()
};

vm.myResponse.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    myfunction(computedValue);
});


var myfunction = function (observableToUpdate) {
    var responses = request.responses();
    return changeUp.getUserInfo().then(function (userInfo) {
        var currentResponse = ko.utils.arrayFirst(responses, function (r) {
            return r.userName === userInfo.userName;
        });
        var responseindex = responses.indexOf(currentResponse);
        observableToUpdate({
            responeIndex: responseindex
        });
    });
};
```

On my html I'm using following lines

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: request.responses()">
<tr data-bind="css: { responder : $parent.vm}">
    <td>{{since()}}</td>
    <td>{{amount|number}}</td>
    <td>{{rate|number}}</td>
    <td>{{distance}}</td>
    <td>
        <a data-bind="click: action">{{_t('Details')}}</a>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Currently non of the  get the class responder. i want to add it only if the condition in isMyResponse is true;

Comment: It looks like you are using promises, so I suspect that it is an order of execution issue for your logging.

As a test change one of the `console.log("outside" + test);` to something else to see if that is the case.

Comment: @NathanFisher is correct.  getUserInfo must be an asynchronous method.  If you look at the order of the console writes you see that the 2 "then" callbacks are executed AFTER the method has returned, therefore "test" is still undefined at the return statement.  You cannot use this approach retutrn a value for a computed.

Comment: Based on your latest edit, there is a lot of information missing from you sample javascript...  Can you please flesh out `request`, including `responses`.  Also `isMyResponse` is not present in either javascript or HTML sample

Comment: The comment "Currently non of the get the class responder" doesn't make sense.   It also looks like you are using mustache/handlebar style binding syntax, are you using an Binding extension ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to use asynchonous callbacks to set an observable is to use subscriptions.  A knockout computed expects a synchronous return value.

You function finished execution before the "then" callbacks fire.

```
var someObservable = ko.observable();
var computedValue = ko.observable();

someObservable.subscribe( function( newValue ) {
    changeup.getUserInfo().then( function(userInfo) {
        ...
        computedValue(myRespondIndex);
    });
} );
```

Also, "then" callback return value only influences the call chain of the promise.  If you throw an exception the fail callback will fire and any chained "then" callback will not be invoked.  A returned value does not "cascade" through the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

For the `UserID = 'undefined'`, I think that the result of the first `then` function is being passed to the second `then` function.  The result of the second `then` function will be `undefined` as nothing is returned. I think it should probably be something like this:-

```
this.isMyResponse = function(index) {
    var test ;
    var responses = this.request.responses();
    var useriD = changeup.getUserInfo().then(function (userInfo) {
        var currentResponse = ko.utils.arrayFirst(responses, function (r) {
            return r.username === userInfo.username;
        });
        var myRespondIndex = responses.indexOf(currentResponse);
        test = myRespondIndex;
        console.log("inside" + test);
        return myRespondIndex;
    }).then  (function (index) {
        console.log("outside" + test);
        return index;
    });
    console.log("outside" + test);
    return test;
}
```

**EDIT**
The following jsFiddle was my attempt to confirm what Robert Stanley was telling me. In the end I implemented the solution how he suggested.

http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/zdDh9/

As Robert Stanley pointed out to me, the following javascript will return a promise but the not values that I thought it was going to.

```
var isMyResponse = function(observableToUpdate) {
    var responses = this.request.responses();
    return  changeup.getUserInfo().then(function (userInfo) {
        var currentResponse = ko.utils.arrayFirst(responses, function (r) {
            return r.username === userInfo.username;
         });
         return {
             responeIndex: responses.indexOf(currentResponse),
             userInfo: userInfo
         };
    });
}
```

Comment: The 2 "then" callback functions are executed asynchronously after the method returns.

Comment: yea, I know. the issue was why the UserID was undefined

Comment: userId equals the promise, not the result

Comment: the way it currently stands the userId is not used for anything.

Comment: the return values in the promise callback are not useable and are meaningless.  In your code above the return value of isMyResponse is the promise, not the return value of the then callback

Comment: +1 Robert. You're right.  I went back to the Q docs.  Thanks for the re-education :-)  updating the code.

Comment: Hi, thanks. the fiddle doesn't work for me. and neither the code. i don't know what i'm doing wrong. I updated the original code to my current one